# Insertion Sort Implemented in Ruby

Tags: beginner, ruby, insertion-sort

I'm a new programmer and I'm periodically going into the Intro To Algorithms CLRS textbook and trying to translate pseudocode into Ruby for skill practice. This is my implementation/translation of insertion sort.

I'm looking for feedback on readability as well as efficiency.

Pseudocode is found on page 17 of Intro To Algorithms Second Edition just in case you happen to have it lying around, more interested in the feedback just on the code itself.

````
class InsertionSort
    attr_accessor :arr
    def initialize(arr)
      @arr = arr
    end
    
    def sort
      key = 1
      to_the_left = key - 1
      
      while key < self.arr.length
        if arr[key] < arr[to_the_left] 
          
          mover_key = key
          left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left
          
          until arr[mover_key] > arr[left_ele_moving_right] || left_ele_moving_right < 0
            
            arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] = 
            arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]
              
              mover_key -= 1 
              left_ele_moving_right -= 1
          end
        end
        
        key += 1
        to_the_left += 1
      end
      
      self.arr
    end
end

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Consistency

Sometimes you are using 4 spaces for indentation, sometimes 2. Sometimes you are using vertical whitespace (an empty line) before a method definition, sometimes you don't. Sometimes you have whitespace at the end of a line, sometimes you don't. In one case, you indent a couple of lines just for no discernible reason.

You should choose one style and stick with it. If you are editing some existing code, you should adapt your style to be the same as the existing code. If you are part of a team, you should adapt your style to match the rest of the team.

Most communities have developed standardized community style guides. In Ruby, there are multiple such style guides. They all agree on the basics (e.g. indentation is 2 spaces), but they might disagree on more specific points (single quotes or double quotes).

In general, if you use two different ways to write the exact same thing, the reader will think that you want to convey a message with that. So, you should only use two different ways of writing the same thing *IFF* you actually *want* to convey some extra information.

For example, some people always use parentheses for defining and calling purely functional side-effect free methods, and never use parentheses for defining and calling impure methods. That is a *good* reason to use two different styles (parentheses and no parentheses) for doing the same thing (defining methods).

## Indentation

The community standard for indentation is 2 spaces. For example, your first two lines should look like this:

```ruby
class InsertionSort
  attr_accessor :arr
```

Instead of this:

```ruby
class InsertionSort
    attr_accessor :arr
```

Furthermore, you should only indent in places where there is a logically nested structure, e.g. a method definition inside a class definition, the body of the method definition, the body of a block, etc. An exception is a continuation of the previous line, this should also be indented.

Here, you are indenting for no apparent reason:

```ruby
arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]

  mover_key -= 1 
  left_ele_moving_right -= 1
```

On the other hand, in the same place, you *should* indent this:

```ruby
arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
  arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]
```

To make it clear that the second line is a continuation of the first.

## No whitespace at the end of the line

There should be no whitespace at the end of the line. For example, this line:

```ruby
if arr[key] < arr[to_the_left]
```

Has a space at the end. That shouldn't be there. And there are two more lines like this.

Also, there are multiple "empty" lines that actually contain *only* spaces. Again, those shouldn't be there.

## No empty line at the end of the file

Your file should end with a single newline. There should not be an extra empty line at the end of the file.

## Vertical whitespace

There should be a blank line after every "logical" break. In particular, there should be a blank line after the `attr_accessor`:

```ruby
attr_accessor :arr

def initialize(arr)
```

On the other hand, there should be no empty line directly after the `if` and the `until`.

Otherwise, your use of vertical whitespace looks good! Logical steps in the method are clearly separated by empty lines, the code looks "light", not all bunched together with "room to breathe". I like it, well done!

## `self` is the implicit receiver

In Ruby, if you don't explicitly specify the receiver of a message send, the receiver is `self`. In idiomatic code, you should never explicitly specify the receiver `self`, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Right now, I can only think of two cases, where it would be necessary:

- To use an attribute writer method: `self.foo = bar`.
- To use an operator: `self + foo`

So, this:

```ruby
self.arr
```

should just be:

```ruby
arr
```

Same here:

```ruby
while key < self.arr.length
```

should be

```ruby
while key < arr.length
```

## Prefer predicate methods over relational operators

You should prefer "speaking" predicate methods such as [`Numeric#negative?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-negative-3F) over relational operators such as `< 0`.

So, this:

```ruby
left_ele_moving_right < 0
```

should be

```ruby
left_ele_moving_right.negative?
```

## Code Formatting

If possible, you should set your editor or IDE to automatically format your code when you type, when you paste, and when you save, and set up your version control system to automatically format your commit when you push, as well as set up your CI system to reject code that is not correctly formatted. If not possible, you should seriously consider using a different editor or IDE, version control system, or CI system.

Here's the result of your code, when I simply paste it into my editor, without doing anything else:

```ruby
class InsertionSort
  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end

  def sort
    key = 1
    to_the_left = key - 1

    while key < arr.length
      if arr[key] < arr[to_the_left]

        mover_key = key
        left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left

        until arr[mover_key] > arr[left_ele_moving_right] || left_ele_moving_right < 0

          arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
            arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]

          mover_key -= 1
          left_ele_moving_right -= 1
        end
      end

      key += 1
      to_the_left += 1
    end

    arr
  end
end
```

As you can see, simply copying your code into my editor, the editor corrected every single thing I wrote above except one.

## Linting

You should run some sort of linter or static analyzer on your code. [Rubocop](https://www.rubocop.org/) is a popular one, but there are others.

Rubocop was able to detect all of the style violations I pointed out above (plus some more), and also was able to autocorrect all of the ones I listed.

Let me repeat that: I have just spent two pages pointing out how to correct tons of stuff that you can *actually* correct within milliseconds at the push of a button. I have set up my editor such that it automatically runs Rubocop with auto-fix as soon as I hit "save".

In particular, running Rubocop on your code, it detects 26 offenses, of which it can automatically correct 23.

Here's what the result of the auto-fix looks like:

```ruby
class InsertionSort
  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end

  def sort
    key = 1
    to_the_left = key - 1

    while key < arr.length
      if arr[key] < arr[to_the_left]

        mover_key = key
        left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left

        until arr[mover_key] > arr[left_ele_moving_right] || left_ele_moving_right.negative?

          arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
            arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]

          mover_key -= 1
          left_ele_moving_right -= 1
        end
      end

      key += 1
      to_the_left += 1
    end

    arr
  end
end
```

And here are the offenses that Rubocop could not automatically correct:

```
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

insertion_sort.rb:1:1: C: Style/Documentation: Missing top-level class documentation comment.
class InsertionSort
^^^^^
insertion_sort.rb:8:3: C: Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for sort is too high. [<10, 21, 7> 24.29/17]
  def sort ...
  ^^^^^^^^
insertion_sort.rb:8:3: C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [17/10]
  def sort ...
  ^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 3 offenses detected
```

Similar to Code Formatting, it is a good idea to set up your tools such that the linter is automatically run when you paste code, edit code, save code, commit code, or build your project, and that passing the linter is a criterium for your CI pipeline.

## `attr_reader` vs. `attr_accessor`

You are never writing to `arr`, so it should probably be a [`Module#attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) instead of a [`Module#attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```ruby
attr_reader :arr
```

## Access Restrictions

`arr` is not intended to be used by other objects. In fact, it *shouldn't* be used by other objects! It is private internal state of the sorter object. Therefore, it should not be part of the public API, it should be [`private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private):

```ruby
private attr_reader :arr
```

## Iterators

In Ruby, you almost never use loops. You would normally use *at least* an low-level iterator such as [`Kernel#loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), `#each`, or [`Integer#times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times). Really, you want to use higher-level iterators such as [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), etc.

In this case, we are going to use `Integer#times` for the outer loop.

```ruby
def sort
  arr.length.times do |key|
    to_the_left = key - 1

    if arr[key] < arr[to_the_left]
      mover_key = key
      left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left

      until arr[mover_key] > arr[left_ele_moving_right] || left_ele_moving_right.negative?
        arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
          arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]

        mover_key -= 1
        left_ele_moving_right -= 1
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

## Guard clauses

If you have a case where an entire method or block is wrapped in a conditional, you can replace that with a "guard clause" and reduce the level of nesting.

E.g. this:

```rb
def something
  if foo
    bar
    baz
    quux
  else
    42
  end
end
```

can become this:

```rb
def something
  return 42 unless foo

  bar
  baz
  quux
end
```

After the above change, there is now an opportunity to do that in your code:

```ruby
def sort
  arr.length.times do |key|
    to_the_left = key - 1

    next unless arr[key] < arr[to_the_left]

    mover_key = key
    left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left

    until arr[mover_key] > arr[left_ele_moving_right] || left_ele_moving_right.negative?
      arr[left_ele_moving_right], arr[mover_key] =
        arr[mover_key], arr[left_ele_moving_right]

      mover_key -= 1
      left_ele_moving_right -= 1
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

## Objects

I don't see a particular reason why insertion sort should be an object. It doesn't have any state (having the array to be sorted, as you do, as state is somewhat weird), and it only has a simple single behavior. It would make more sense for a sorting algorithm to be an object if it carries some complex state that persists between different runs of the algorithm.

In a language which supports procedures or functions, this should probably be a function.

In Ruby, I would make it maybe a singleton method of a module, or an instance method of [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). However, I would not name it `sort` because that method already exists. I would also not name it `insertion_sort` because that is an implementation detail. I think `stable_sort` would be a good name, because the fact that insertion sort is *stable* (if implemented correctly) is an important distinguishing feature that sets it apart from the default `sort` in Ruby, which is not stable.

So, either something like this:

```ruby
module Sort
  module_function def stable_sort(arr)
    # …
  end
end
```

or something like this:

```ruby
class Array
  def stable_sort
    length.times do |key|
      # …
    end
  end
end
```

Actually, I am not a big fan of monkey-patching core classes. *At least* put the method in a separate mixin, so that it is easier to trace where the code is coming from:

```ruby
module StableSortExtension
  def stable_sort
    length.times do |key|
      # …
    end
  end
end

class Array
  include StableSortExtension
end
```

But even better would be to make it a *Refinement*:

```ruby
module StableSort
  module StableSortExtension
    def stable_sort
      length.times do |key|
        to_the_left = key - 1

        next unless self[key] < self[to_the_left]

        mover_key = key
        left_ele_moving_right = to_the_left

        while self[mover_key] <= self[left_ele_moving_right] && left_ele_moving_right >= 0

          self[left_ele_moving_right], self[mover_key] =
            self[mover_key], self[left_ele_moving_right]

          mover_key -= 1
          left_ele_moving_right -= 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

  refine Array do
    include StableSortExtension
  end
end
```

Now, the `Array#stable_sort` method will *only* exist for code which *explicitly* activates the Refinement with

```ruby
using StableSort
```

Observe:

```ruby
ary = [5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0, 10]

ary.stable_sort
# undefined method `stable_sort' for [5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0, 10]:Array (NoMethodError)

using StableSort

ary.stable_sort

p ary
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

However, I would not do it this way. This `stable_sort` method mutates its receiver, which is generally not the case for other `sort` methods in Ruby, and thus very surprising to people.

So, the method should at least `dup` the receiver and perform its mutations on that duplicate, then return it.

Which brings me to my next point:

## Mutation

Your method mutates its argument. That is an absolute no-go. You should *never-ever* break someone else's toy. An argument that is handed to you, is *sacred*.

You can fix this by simply adding something like `arr = arr.dup` at the beginning of the method (or `arr = dup` for the case where you want to make it an instance method). But I believe we can improve the code more generally.

More generally, your code looks more like FORTRAN, Pascal, or C, with lots of mutation, looping, manual fiddling with indices.

Insertion sort can actually be expressed very elegantly without mutation and without looping, which will not only simplify the code, but also get rid of the mutation problem.

Something like this:

```ruby
module Enumerable
  protected def ins(element)
    return [element] if count.zero?

    head = first
    return [element] + self if element <= head

    [head] + drop(1).ins(element)
  end

  def stable_sort
    return [] if count.zero?

    drop(1).stable_sort.ins(first)
  end
end
```

This version does not mutate anything, and it works with *all* [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html)s (including [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html)s), not just `Array`s. (It does not work with *infinite* `Enumerator`s, though.)

## Frozen string literals

Immutable data structures and purely functional code are always preferred, unless mutability and side-effects are required for clarity or performance. In Ruby, strings are always mutable, but there is a [magic comment](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8976) you can add to your files (also available as a command-line option for the Ruby engine), which will automatically make all literal strings immutable:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

It is generally preferred to add this comment to all your files.

Note: I put this at the very end, because there actually are no `String` literals in your code, so it doesn't matter. Rubocop and some other Linters will complain about this regardless. It's your choice whether you want to get into the habit of *always* adding it, regardless of whether you use `String` literals in the code or not. Personally, I always add it, just in case I add a `String` literal later on.

Comment: What is the purpose of StableSortExtension?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: "put the method in a separate mixin, so that it is easier to trace where the code is coming from". Now, if you do something like `Array.ancestors`, `StableSortExtension` will show up in the inheritance tree, and if you are wondering where this `stable_sort` method that you never heard about and never noticed before comes from, you can probably guess it came from there.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is undoubtedly the easiest-to-understand and easiest-to-code sorting method, requiring but one line of Ruby code. It seems overkill in the extreme to define a class with instance variables and multiple instance methods. I have written a single method `insertion_sort`.

If desired it could be written as a module method in a module that could be required as needed. Assuming you wished to compare sorting methods (considering that the more efficient built-in methods [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort), [Enumerable#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) would be the methods of choice for general sorting needs) you might create a module such as the following.

```
module SortingMethods
  def self.insertion_sort(arr)
    ...
  end

  def self.bubble_sort(arr)
    ...
  end
       
  ...

end
```

The method would then be invoked

```
sorted = SortingMethods.insertion_sort(arr)
```

This is analogous to the use of the built-in [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Math.html) module, which contains module methods only, methods that would serve as *functions* (which are not invoked on receivers) in other languages.

The method `insertion_sort` can be written is as follows.

```
def insertion_sort(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |o, sorted|
    sorted.insert(sorted.bsearch_index { |e| e >= o } || sorted.size, o)
  end
end
```

```
insertion_sort [8, 29, 10, 20, 26, 5, 20, 2]
  #=> [2, 5, 8, 10, 20, 20, 26, 29]
```

```
insertion_sort ["dog", "cat", "pig", "owl", "cow", "bat"]
  #=> ["bat", "cat", "cow", "dog", "owl", "pig"]
```

This relies on two methods.

[Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert)
inserts a given object into `self` before the element at a given index. If that index equals the size of (the array that is) `self`, the element is inserted after the last element of `self`.

[Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) returns the index of the element of `sorted` before which a given object is to be inserted in order to keep `sorted` sorted. `nil` is returned if the given object is greater than the last element of `sorted` (hence the need for `|| sorted.size`). See also [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) for details.

Note that the argument is not mutated (modified).

The easiest way to demonstrate the calculations is to run the code after having salted it with `puts` statements. I will write the code in a simpler way that effectively performs the same operations.

```
arr = [8, 29, 10, 20, 26, 5, 20, 2]
```

```
sorted = []
arr.each do |o|
  puts "\no = #{o}, sorted = #{sorted}"
  idx = sorted.bsearch_index { |e| e >= o }
  puts "idx from bsearch initially = #{ idx.nil? ? 'nil' : idx }"
  idx = idx || sorted.size
  puts "idx after 'idx || sorted' = #{idx}"
  sorted.insert(idx, o)
  puts "sorted after sorted.insert(#{idx}, #{o}) = #{sorted}"
end
```

```
o = 8, sorted = []
idx from bsearch initially = nil
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 0
sorted after sorted.insert(0, 8) = [8]
```

```
o = 29, sorted = [8]
idx from bsearch initially = nil
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 1
sorted after sorted.insert(1, 29) = [8, 29]
```

```
o = 10, sorted = [8, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 1
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 1
sorted after sorted.insert(1, 10) = [8, 10, 29]
```

```
o = 20, sorted = [8, 10, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 2
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 2
sorted after sorted.insert(2, 20) = [8, 10, 20, 29]
```

```
o = 26, sorted = [8, 10, 20, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 3
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 3
sorted after sorted.insert(3, 26) = [8, 10, 20, 26, 29]
```

```
o = 5, sorted = [8, 10, 20, 26, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 0
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 0
sorted after sorted.insert(0, 5) = [5, 8, 10, 20, 26, 29]
```

```
o = 20, sorted = [5, 8, 10, 20, 26, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 3
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 3
sorted after sorted.insert(3, 20) = [5, 8, 10, 20, 20, 26, 29]
```

```
o = 2, sorted = [5, 8, 10, 20, 20, 26, 29]
idx from bsearch initially = 0
idx after 'idx || sorted' = 0
sorted after sorted.insert(0, 2) = [2, 5, 8, 10, 20, 20, 26, 29]
```

Comment: It was in reference to a different answer to this review. I've deleted it to avoid any further confusion.